# Select all rows in table A that contains keyword in table B - SQL Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

On a Redshift database, I have a SQL table A with hundred of thousands of rows. This table has a field "name" containing strings.
Something like:

```
|           Name         |
| ---------------------- |
| Thor                   |
| Spiderman              |
| The Amazing Spiderman  |
| Superman               |
| Hulk                   |
| Jonas The Fish         |
| Fish Billy             |
```

I also have a table B containing thousands of rows with a field name "Keywords" and containing... keywords. Something like:

```
|        Keyword      |
| --------------------|
| Amazing Spiderman   |
| Fish                |
```

I want to select all rows from table A that contains a keyword within table B. So my result should be something like:

```
|           Name         |
| ---------------------- |
| The Amazing Spiderman  |
| Jonas The Fish         |
| Fish Billy             |
```

What would be the correct way to make it happen please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the wildcard character with `table_B.keyword`

The concatenation operator and the wildcard character may vary depending on the database

**MySQL, MariaDB**

```sql
SELECT Table_A.name 
FROM Table_A, Table_B
WHERE Table_A.name LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(Table_B.keyword,'%'))
```

**SQL Server**

```sql
SELECT Table_A.name 
FROM Table_A, Table_B
WHERE Table_A.name LIKE '%' + Table_B.keyword + '%'
```

**Oracle DB**

```sql
SELECT Table_A.name 
FROM Table_A, Table_B
WHERE Table_A.name LIKE '%' || Table_B.keyword || '%'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. I already tried this code and my results were weird. Thank to you I had the confirmation the code was right and realized my issue came from some bad keywords.